# How to validate a Django Form field against a FK field

Tags: django, validation, forms

I am attempting to create a validation rule that passes an error if the (milestone)objects target_date is greater then the projects target_date. The issue is that none of the errors are being raised.

For simplicities sake,

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    target_date = models.DateField()

class Milestone(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    target_date = models.DateField()
```

Forms.py

```
class MilestoneAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Milestone

    def clean_target_date(self):
        tdate = self.cleaned_data['target_date']
        if tdate > self.instance.project.target_date
            raise forms.ValidationError("Target Date is outside or project target date.")
        return tdate
```

views.py(dropped unrelated code)

```
def MilestoneManage(request, project_id):
    qs = Project.objects.none()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = MilestoneFormSet(request.POST, prefix='new')
        if formset.is_valid():
            newMiles = formset.save(commit=False)
            for new in newMiles:
                new.project_id = project.id
                new.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project.views.detail', args=(project.id,)))
    else:
        formset = MilestoneFormSet2(queryset=qs, prefix='new')
    return render_to_response('project/manageMilestones.html', {
        'formset': formset,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What's the exact error? And please can you provide code that actually runs (there are at least two syntax errors in the above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  See inline comments for more info on what was changed.

```
def clean_target_date(self):
    #                 V-- typo (cleand_data => cleaned_data)
    tdate = self.cleaned_data['target_date']
    project = self.instance.project
    # project allows for nulls, so check that first.
    if project is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError("There's no project associated with this milestone.")
    #                   V-- Do an attribute lookup, don't use the query lookup syntax
    if tdate > project.target_date:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Target Date is outside or project target date.")
    return tdate
```

Comment: @Dronestudios: Are you sure target_date is greater than the projects' target_date?  What happens if you debug into it?

Comment: Still a relatively new at django and my debugging foo is weak at the moment. It will most likely take me a little bit to figure out what's going on. It seems as if none of this code is getting called.

Comment: It may be,  try throwing in a `raise` at the beginning of `cleaned_target_date`.  If you don't see an exception then it's not being called.  If this happens, update your question with your `Milestone` model definition.

Comment: Yeah it looks like even doing that isn't happening. Could this be due to using formsets?  Added views.py

Comment: Yeah, it works on my normal forms. There must be something different about formsets.

Comment: @Dronestudio: What ended up being the problem?

Comment: It turns out you need to move the code you wrote to clean on a baseformset. I haven't gotten it to work yet but this got me to the write place.   The current issue is on a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081784/django-custom-validation-on-formsets