# Django validating fields in a formset against another form being processed at the same time

Tags: django, validation, formsets

This one might be a bit complicated or I am just confused

I have two forms on a single page. One is a form and the other is a formset. My goal is to validate fields in the formset against fields in the form. My guess on what is currently happening is that the method that I am passing the Project forms ID to the formset is happening in a way that it's not being picked up for the formsets validation.

It errors out on

```
if target > project.target_date:
```

Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'target_date'

The code that currently works with out validation: Note, I am setting project to allow null on the Milestones model. I would prefer it to not allow null but this was the only way I could figure out how to pass the project_id to the Milestones form.

View.py

```
def ProjectAdd(request): #Finish the template
    qs = Project.objects.none()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectAddForm(request.POST)
        formset = MilestoneFormSet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            project = form.save()
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.project_id = project.id
                instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project.views.detail', args=(project.id,)))
    else:
        form = ProjectAddForm()
        formset = MilestoneFormSet(queryset=qs)
    return render_to_response('project/addProjectForm.html', {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
        'current_date': current_date,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Models.py

```
class Milestone(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True)
    target_date = models.DateField('Target Date')
```

forms.py

```
MilestoneFormSet = modelformset_factory(Milestone, extra=1, max_num=50)
```

The code that I would like have work with validation. Right now everything is the same except forms.py:

forms.py

```
class MilestoneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            raise forms.ValidationError("")
        data = self.cleaned_data
        target = data["target_date"]
        project = data["project"]
        if target > project.target_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Target Date is beyond the project target date - Project Target: %s" % target)
        if target < project.start_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Target Date is before the start date of the project - Project Start: %s" % project.start_date)
        return data

MilestoneFormSet = modelformset_factory(Milestone, form=MilestoneForm, extra=1, max_num=50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Milestone.project can be `None`.

When you do `project = data['project']` follow it on by a check `if project is None: raise forms.ValidationError('No project is assigned to this milestone.'`

I mentioned this your previous question [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046764/how-to-validate-a-django-form-field-against-a-fk-field/4046796#4046796), must have missed it :).

Comment: When I set project to project = models.ForeignKey(Project) to force it to not allow a null value, the milestones fail validation. The error is missing project since the project does not exist until form.save is ran. Unless there is another way to handle that? Is it possible to run form.save() and pass the recently create project_id back to the formset?

Comment: Right now I am doing this to get the project_id to the milestone formset. ----         project = form.save()
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.project_id = project.id
                instance.save()

Comment: I think for a cleaner way to describe my issue is using this example. How would I run a clean on this example so that I could validate values from the second form against the first.  http://goo.gl/ADjpL

Comment: I gave up on going this route. Switching to just passing the first forms project.id into the milestones formset page. Easier. Thanks for trying